# PHP Evaluate Variables Look For Best Fit

Tags: php

Assuming I have four values:

```
$right 
$down
$left
$up
```

And I want to choose the best out of the four. The values can either be `false`, `0`, `1-9`, or `D`.

False is the worst, 0 is second, 1-9 varies obviously 9 is best, and finally D is the best of all (stands of double).

What is best way to check this in PHP? I was thinking first check for D in all variables. If no D, then look for the highest number in all four, then look for 0, then finally look for false.

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: assign each value a weight.  `false => 0, 0 => 1, 1 => 2, ..., 9 => 10, D => 11`.  Then, make an array of like `$arr('right' => weight, 'left' => weight, ...)` then sort the array.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're interested in the result of `up`, `down`, `left` or `right` in the end, so it'd make sense to keep those as *values* in an array paired with their "strength" values and simply sort them. Rough, untested draft:

```
$values = array(
    array('type' => 'right', 'value' => false),
    array('type' => 'down',  'value' => 3)
    ...
);

usort($values, function ($a, $b) {
    static $order = array(false, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'D');

    $a = array_search($a['value'], $order, true);
    $b = array_search($b['value'], $order, true);
    return $a - $b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert it to an array first (you could use [`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) for that, or just store in an array to begin with), and then you could use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) with a user-defined comparison function:

```
function myCompare($a, $b)
{
    // Convert false and D to -1 and 10, respectively.
    $a = ($a === false ? -1 : ($a == 'D' ? 10 : $a));
    $b = ($b === false ? -1 : ($b == 'D' ? 10 : $b));

    return ($b - $a);
}

$arr = compact('right', 'down', 'left', 'up');

uasort($arr, 'myCompare');
```

Or on PHP 5.3+, you could use a closure:

```
$arr = compact('right', 'down', 'left', 'up');

uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    // Convert false and D to -1 and 10, respectively.
    $a = ($a === false ? -1 : ($a == 'D' ? 10 : $a));
    $b = ($b === false ? -1 : ($b == 'D' ? 10 : $b));

    return ($b - $a);
});
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but the resulting array is empty? See pastie: http://pastie.org/3947730

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the answer you are looking for.

```
$test['up'] = false;
$test['down'] = 4;
$test['left'] = 'D';
$test['right'] = 0;

// for display only
print_r($test);

asort($test,SORT_STRING);

// for display only
print_r($test);

// Array key of the last value in array / best
echo array_pop(array_keys($test));
```

Comment: btw, the two print_r statements are simply there to see the results.  Otherwise, not important.